# Blank option added for selected option as language changes

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-translate

I have the following code to show a multiselect with some options. All options are translated using a translation filter (angular-translate).

```
<select multiple class="form-control" ng-model="field.value">
    <option ng-repeat="option in field.options()">{{option.name | translate}}</option>
</select>
```

It will produce something like this:

```
['Orange', 'Apple', 'Banana']
```

If some options are selected and the language is changed, angularjs will not find a match for the selected items ('Orange' != 'Apelsin'), so it will add empty ones and I will end up with:

```
[' ', ' ', 'Apelsin', 'Äpple', 'Banan']
```

How can I avoid that the change of language messes up my select list? I would want to put an ID on each option, so that it will try to match that instead of the translated name.

Comment: what is in `field.options()`?

Comment: In my example, the fruits, so: ['Orange', 'Apple', 'Banana']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep translated name inside  tag, but also use un-translated name as value attribute of option.

```
<option ng-repeat="option in options">{{option | translate }}
```

to

```
<option value="{{option}}" ng-repeat="option in options">{{option | translate }}
```

It's not Angular specific http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_value.asp

I had same issue and this solved it to me...

---

Plus, set some option as default in controller

Template

```
ng-model="field.value"
```

Controller

```
$scope.field.value = options[0] // First will be selected by default
```

Comment: I'm marking this answer as the correct one, but it should be value="{{option.name}}" or value="{{option.id}}" which I ended up with. Thanks! :)

Comment: Yep, I simplified the code to made it more general. I'm glad it helped :)

Comment: Forgetting to add the {{}} will lead to all values being set to the string "option" though. :)